# .net SqlDataReader VB C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sqldatareader

I have this statement:

```
if (sqlClass.Reader != null && sqlClass.Reader.HasRows)
    {
        do
        {
            data = sqlClass.Reader.GetString(0); //error line System.InvalidOperationException {"Invalid attempt to read when no data is present."}
        } while (sqlClass.Reader.Read());
    }
```

the object `sqlClass.Reader` is of type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader`

In C# it gives me an `InvalidOperationException` but in VB it worked fine, what would the reason be and how do I solve this?

Comment: show the entire error and the line of error too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if (null != sqlClass.Reader)
{
    while (sqlClass.Reader.Read())
    {
        data = sqlClass.Reader.GetString(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: damn you beat me to it. I was going to write just that. its a matter of using a different type of while loop as you demonstrated

Comment: You'd rather had preserved `qlClass.Reader != null`

Comment: `sqlClass.Reader.HasRows` if of no use here

Comment: HasRows checks if the reader has retrieved data. The null check will just check if the object is not null.